# Rendering a plane parallel to virtual camera OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, rendering

I want to render a plane that is always parallel to the virtual camera and rotates with the same rotation as the camera. I tried to apply the view matrix to the plane but it doesn't move as I expect it to move. This is my view matrix:

```
view.setToIdentity();
view.rotate(m_rotation.conjugate());
view.translate(-m_translation);
```

These are my camera's vectors:

```
const QVector3D Camera3D::LocalForward(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
const QVector3D Camera3D::LocalUp(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
const QVector3D Camera3D::LocalRight(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

and my quad:

```
float x0 = -(float)32.f, y0 = -(float)32.f;
float x1 =  (float)32.f, y1 = (float)32.f;
   // Set attributes
const QVector3D vertices[4] = {
    QVector3D( x0, y0, 0.0f),
    QVector3D( x0, y1, 0.0f),
    QVector3D( x1, y1, 0.0f),
    QVector3D( x1, y0, 0.0f)
};


const QVector3D normals[4] = {
    QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
    QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
    QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f),
    QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f)
};
const QVector2D texcoords[4] = {
    QVector2D(0.0f, 1.0f),
    QVector2D(0.0f, 0.0f),
    QVector2D(1.0f, 0.0f),
    QVector2D(1.0f, 1.0f)
};


const unsigned int indices[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
// const unsigned int indices[4] = { 3, 2, 1, 0 };

shProgram.enableAttributeArray("vVertices");
shProgram.enableAttributeArray("vTexCoords");
shProgram.enableAttributeArray("vNormals");

shProgram.setAttributeArray("vVertices", vertices);
shProgram.setAttributeArray("vTexCoords", texcoords);
shProgram.setAttributeArray("vNormals", normals);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);



shProgram.disableAttributeArray("vVertices");
shProgram.disableAttributeArray("vTexCoords");
shProgram.disableAttributeArray("vNormals");
```

I'm using QOpenGLWindow from Qt. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *" I tried to apply the view matrix to the plane but it doesn't move as I expect"* - You have to be more specific. How does it move and how do you expect that it should move? Where is the relevant code part, which applies the rotation to the plane? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what you are trying to do is called as Billboard(plan/Quad) always parallel to camera . You can find lots of nice tutorial on how to render it.

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni thanks a lot! it solved my problem!